# Laravel's Middleware not working on Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I have a middleware called 'AdminMiddleware', which is being used in the constructor of a class. For some reason the middleware is not called from the constructor, although the constructor function is being run. I tried doing a die dump on the adminMiddleware file but it seems like it just ignores this file.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\SuperAdmin;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

        class dashboard extends Controller
        {
            protected $user;

            public function __construct()
                {
                    $this->middleware('admin');
                    $this->user = Auth::User();
                }

//Kernel.php
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'superadmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\SuperAdminMiddleware::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,
    ];
```

For some project requirements i cant use the middleware directly on the routes. Any help is appreciated, i am using laravel 5.1.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to do 2 things to enable middleware in the controller:

1. Register middleware in $routeMiddleware in your App\Http\Kernel.php

   protected $routeMiddleware = [
       'admin'        => 'App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware',
   ];
2. Enable middleware in your controller, using middleware's key, not class name:

   $this->middleware('admin');

Comment: well i have added 'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware to the $routeMiddleware array, but it still doesn't work. But it works on the $globalMiddleware array, but once i do that, i cant logout. 
I have also tried 'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware::class,

Comment: You added the middleware, go to any route from this controller and middleware is not executed?

Comment: No its not executed when added to the $routeMiddleware, but when added to $middleware array it does executes but then its called on every request. I have made an edit and this is what the controller and kernel looks like now.

Comment: The code you pasted works for me. How are you testing that?

Comment: well i am just doing a die dump on the middleware, to check if its executed. BTW i am calling the function like this, because i have a wierd senario where i have to do this.   return $controller = app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\Admin\dashboard')->index();

Comment: If you run controller action this way no wonder middleware doesn't get executed. Middleware is called by Laravel kernel when incoming request is processed by Kernel and before the action is called. It won't work if you execute controller method the way you do.

Comment: I think i get your point, so is there any other alternative to this? I just want to do a quick check on the constructor to check whether the user has a role of admin.

Comment: if (in_array('admin', Auth::user()->roles))?

Comment: well actually its not that simple i am using entrust for ACL, so there are some other rules as well to check for. But i guess there is no other way then to hard code them inside the controller. Thanks jedrzej for your answer :)

Comment: no problem. but if I were you I'd try to find out how to run the controller the normal way, it will be much simpler then

Comment: yes that would be awesome if i could find a simple way to running the controller. If you are interested, here is my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368433/single-laravel-route-for-multiple-controllers/31368819

Comment: I don't know why when we call full name like $this->middleware(\App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class) it work

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the same issue, and apparently route caching also caches middlewares.

So `php artisan route:clear` solved it in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, and solve it by composer dump-autoload.
My problem is change the file name and not regenerate the autoload.
I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer, dont remember what the issue was. But i agree dump autoload does solve most of the problems :P

Answer (score 0):

Using Laravel Framework 9.46.0 doesn't work for me also with the key 'admin', changing it to 'administrator' or 'admin.only' works. it's like 'admin' is a reserved word.