# Laravel 5.2 assigning same route to different controller action by conditions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes

I wish to route the same route to different controller base on user type.

Such as

```
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_admin) {
        Route::get('/profile', 'AdminController@show');
    } elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_superadmin) {
        Route::get('/profile', 'SuperAdminController@show');
    }
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I make it works as what I want?

Comment: Is there a major difference between your super admin controller vs the admin controller? I personally would route to the same controller and use the Auth logic to determine which method on the controller to execute. It is not usually a best practice to have logic in your routes file

Comment: Thanks Rob, I understood it is not a good practice to do so.  Admin and SuperAdmin will have a very different dashboard and functions in my system.  Thats why I wish to separate them into 2 controllers and actions.

Comment: here goes your answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368433/single-laravel-route-for-multiple-controllers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
    Route::get('/profile', 'HomeController@profile'); // another route
```

**Controller**

```
    public function profile() {
         if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_admin) {
           $test = app('App\Http\Controllers\AdminController')->getshow();

          }
         elseif (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_superadmin) {
         $test = app('App\Http\Controllers\SuperAdminController')->getshow();
         // this must not return a view but it will return just the needed data , you can pass parameters like this `->getshow($param1,$param2)`

         }

        return View('profile')->with('data', $test);
           }
```

But i think its better to use a trait

```
trait Show {

    public function showadmin() {
    .....
    }
    public function showuser() {
    .....
    }
}
```

Then

```
class HomeController extends Controller {
     use Show;
}
```

Then you can do the same as the above but instead of

```
   $test = app('App\Http\Controllers\AdminController')->getshow();// or the other one
```

use this

```
$this->showadmin();
$this->showuser(); // and use If statment ofc
```

Comment: Thanks for both, finally it works with HomeController as middle man.  It seems it is the only solution at this moment.  thanks a lot again.

Comment: Never mind about the edit it dosent work , Glad it works for you anyway

Answer (score 1):

okey you can do that by creating a `route::group`

your route group will be like that

```
    route::group(['prefix'=>'yourPrefix','middleware'=>'yourMiddleware'],function(){

        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->is_admin)
        {
            Route::get('profile', 'AdminController@show');
        }
        else
        {
            Route::get('profile', 'SuperAdminController@show');
        }

    });
```

I hope that will help you.

Comment: i think its better to keep the logic out of the routes file  :3

Comment: I answered to his question , I replied with what he exactly need to know

Comment: yes of course but never forget about best practices :3

Comment: Thanks H.Fakher, but it does not work in my case, no idea why.  But I make it works with another solution above.  Thanks again.