# Using multiple controllers in the same route gets route undefined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I get an error of undefined route when using multiple controllers in the same route:

Here is the code my controllers:

```
public function triealphabet(){
    $list_grocery = miscellaneous::all();
    $list_grocery = $list_grocery->sortBy('name');
    return view('markets.miscellaneous')->with('list_grocery',$list_grocery);}
public function triecreation(){
    $list_grocery = miscellaneous::all();
    $list_grocery = $list_grocery->sortBy('created_at');
    return view('markets.miscellaneous')->with('list_grocery',$list_grocery);}
```

and here are my routes code :

```
Route::get('/miscellaneous','groceryController@listGrocery')->name('groceriesmarket'); 
Route::get('/miscellaneous','groceryController@triealphabet')->name('triealphabet');
Route::get('/miscellaneous','groceryController@triecreation')->name('triecreation');
```

P.S: If I use an other route path like '/miscellanous-tri-alphabet' I don't get any other errors, but other than that I get an error of undefined route

Comment: does `php artisan route:list` work?

Comment: Where are you getting that error? What are you trying to do? You should never intentionally use multiple controller actions for the same route because the first one to be defined will always be the one used.

Comment: do you have different table in your `view` that displays all the different return?

Comment: @jfadich so there is no other way? because there are some other frameworks that has the ablility to make the same page responding (javascript frameworks), anyway I'm sorry but I'm still a beginner in this field

Answer (score 0):

You can check here: [Laravel 5.2 assigning same route to different controller action by conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871749/laravel-5-2-assigning-same-route-to-different-controller-action-by-conditions?answertab=votes#tab-top). It's not mine but he as an approach of creating new route and a trait.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3 routes has same http method and uri, so only the last route keeped in route collection. So 2 routes before is undefined. You can see details at class:
`Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php` line 65

```
/**
 * Add the given route to the arrays of routes.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route
 * @return void
 */
protected function addToCollections($route)
{
    $domainAndUri = $route->getDomain().$route->uri();

    foreach ($route->methods() as $method) {
        $this->routes[$method][$domainAndUri] = $route;
    }

    $this->allRoutes[$method.$domainAndUri] = $route;
}
```